# Can't figure out how to segment overlapped digits from captcha

Tags: opencv, captcha, image-segmentation

i'm writing an application for solving captcha. Original captcha looks like this:
[Original captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrWCP.png)

After I apply erosion+dilation it looks like this:
[erosion+dilation applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caIjx.png)

Finally I find contours for further segmentation. Obviously, I can cut "1" from the image as it's not connected with other digits. But how can I separate 5 from 7, and 7 from 8, and two zeros on the right in this case? On the first link I see that 5 and 7 are not overlapped, this way i can somehow remember it and use after applying erosion+dilation. Maybe drawing white vertical line. But still i have problems with 7 and 8. 
Any help and advises are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a technique called skeletonization, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton
It will help in this specific case.